# SQL : The name false is not permitted in this context

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

On executing the following SQL query

```
alter table tablename add columnname boolean not null default false;
```

I got the following error message:

`The name "false" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.`

How should I fix this? Suggestions?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question?  It's a common misunderstanding and a perfectly appropriate question.

Comment: ONE MORE REASON FOR GETTING THIS ERROR - You also get this error when you try to insert a value that is not surrounded by single quotes, into a column. Just realized it now and thought of putting it here for everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The column type should be a `bit` field.

In SQL you use `0` and `1` to set a `bit` field. The values are displayed in SQL Server Management Studio as `false` or `true`, corresponding to `0` and `1`.

```
alter table tablename add columnname bit not null default 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `boolean` data type. Use the `bit` data type.

The `false` value for a `bit` is `0`.

```
alter table tablename add columnname bit not null default 0
```

Comment: `Bit` is really a diminutive integer type.  _Truth_ isn't a concept, even if the values are sometimes displayed that way.  If it were, you could write `if Cast( 1 as Bit ) print 'S'truth!'`.

Comment: To clarify for other readers that SQL Server does have a [`BOOLEAN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) data type, but `BIT` isn't it.  You can create instances, but you can't hold on to them.  You wrote that the `false` value for a `bit` is `0`.  What is the `false` value for other data types, e.g. `tinyint`?  What is the `unknown` value?  How much truer is `42`?

Comment: @user92546: You are mistaken. There *is no* boolean data type. Just because there is a *concept* of booleans doesn't mean that there is a data type for it.

Comment: My apologies, you are `!= 0`.  Please follow the link I provided in my previous comment ([`BOOLEAN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)) and inform Microsoft of their documentation error.

Comment: @user92546: Ok, to be clear, there is no boolean *that can be used as a type in a table*. Are you done splitting hairs?